# Why is length property O(n) for linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

According to this really wonderful [book](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganOrderedList.html), "*size, on the other hand, will always require n steps since there is no way to know how many nodes are in the linked list without traversing from head to end. Therefore, length is O(n).*".

I was wondering why can't you have a property in UnorderedList class that can be incremented or decremented when a node is added or removed respectively. Is this specific to the implementation of "size" in this book?

Comment: You could have it as an extra optimisation, but then the fact that you have a linked list is irrelevant. *Calculating* the length of a linked list is `O(n)`. *Remembering it* is a different operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering why can't you have a property in UnorderedList class
>   that can be incremented or decremented when a node is added or removed
>   respectively. Is this specific to the implementation of "size" in this
>   book?

Obviously, some *linked list* implementation may optimize counting its items by incrementing or decrementing a numeric property.

But in absence of that optimization, there's no other way to count *linked list* items than iterating the entire collection.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can keep the length in a variable, so you do not have to query it again and again. The book uses an implementation which does not need this plus variable, but complexity of the size function is O(N). Complexity for size tradeoff.